# Buscar listado de palabras en Python

Tags: python

tengo una lista con palabras que me gustaría buscar dentro de una columna.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este listado de palabras me gustaría buscarlo acá

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si me pudieran orientar a hacer esto, sería genial

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: Lo que me gustaría que apareciera sería una columna indicando la palabra que fue encontrada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba este código, debería funcionarte suponiendo que `texto` es un array con los strings en los que quieres buscar y `listado` las palabras a buscar:

```
resultado = []
for cadena in texto:
    resultado_cadena=[]
    for palabra in listado:
        if cadena.find(palabra) > -1:
          resultado_cadena.append(palabra)
    resultado.append(resultado_cadena)
print(resultado)
```

De esta forma, resultado será una lista que en cada posición contenga una lista de las palabras de listado que ha encontrado en cada una de las cadenas.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, probaré y te comento como me fue :D

Comment: Funcionó, pero me está buscando solo la última palabra

listado=['TAG','Autopista','Patente','Cobro']
Ese es el listado y el resultado es este:

[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['Cobro'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],

Comment: discúlpame, había un error en mi código, ya lo he arreglado, ahora te debería funcionar

Comment: Muchas pero muchas gracias, me acaba de funcionar a la perfección :D

Comment: De nada, me alegro de haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 1):

Python es un lenguaje muy poderoso y no tienes que esforzarte tanto escribiendo lineas de codigo de mas. La palabra reservada del sistema `in` te permitira buscar en listas y strings lo que haga falta.

Sera mejor si lo aprendes a utilizar asi:

```
texto = '''
Un caballo viejo fue vendido para darle vueltas a la piedra de un molino.
Al verse atado a la piedra, exclamó sollozando: - ¡Después de las vueltas
de las carreras, he aquí a que vueltas me he reducido! Moraleja:
No presumáis de la fortaleza de la juventud. Para muchos,
la vejez es un trabajo muy penoso.
'''

por_encontrar = (
    'caballo', 'en', 'aeroplano', 'hola'
)
resultado = [coincidencia for coincidencia in por_encontrar if coincidencia in por_encontrar]

print(f'se ecnotraron las siguientes palabras {resultado}')
```

Un saludo.